# After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Joule, it boots to an UEFI shell

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, uefi

I followed the instructions for developer setup on https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/intel-joule/#dev-setup

to install full Ubuntu on on Intel Joule.

On reboot after install I get this screen

[image: After reboot Screenshot]

Something is not quite right.  What is the next step?

Comment: Could someone create a tag for "Joule"?  My reputation is not high enough.

Comment: What you see is an UEFI shell. Ubuntu's boot loader GRUB or anything else has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Have you updated the BIOS as the instructions said? I don't have such a board or time to investigate what's different in the image you downloaded compared to the regular desktop image. As Byte Commander said this is the UEFI shell telling you that it couldn't find a bootloader, next steps would be to investigate if there is an EFI system partition and if the bootloader got installed into a subdirectory like Ubuntu, try to copy the content to a folder named boot and make a copy of grub or shim named boot. I assume this is related https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1366546